# How to work on personal GitHub repo from office computer whose SSH key is already added to a work related GitHub account?

Tags: github, ssh-keys

I want to work on my personal GitHub repo from office computer whose SSH key is already added to a work related GitHub account .

In my case , I will not be able to add my personal GitHub account as a collaborator for "Work" account's project . I was thinking I can add a new key pair on my office computer , and add it to my personal GitHub account . But will I be able to work on both "Work" and "Personal" repos seamlessly that way ? What's the best way to do this ?

Comment: Have you tried adding that same SSH key to your Personal GitHub account to see if it works?

Comment: @Blender - Yea tried that , since my office computer's SSH key is already added to another GitHub account , it won't let me add the same key to my personal GitHub . It says "key already in use"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add as many public:private key you want, the idea being to register them in %HOME%/.ssh/config file, in order for you to define remote with ssh addresses like:

```
workgh:Work
persgh:Personal
```

See "[change github account mac command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551448/change-github-account-mac-command-line/9551540#9551540)" as an example of an `ssh/config` file.

In your case:

```
#Personal GitHub
Host persgh
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_perso

#Personal Work
Host workgh
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_work
```

Reusing the same ssh key in different environment is genrally frowned upon.
See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890435/creating-a-passphrase-for-my-ssh-key-on-github/10892931#10892931) to generate multiple ssh keys non-interactively.

Comment: I don't understand! How it's gonna distinguish between same hosts to know when uses workRSA, when uses homeRSA!?

Comment: @Dr.jacky because of the private key: each entry references its own private key, whose public key has been registered to a different user.

Answer (score 0):

Coming from a Ruby background , I ended up using "gas" ruby gem . Adding git users was a breeze and it takes care of switching git users along with the keys with a simple command on the terminal :

```
gas use <nickname>
```

Here's this link to the gem : https://github.com/walle/gas

A video on it's features : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-W2vSTwJWJc