# How to use multiple Git SSH keys on Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git, ssh

I looked several answers and forums for a solution but I could not find a single one that works.

I have this scenario:

- Eclipse Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
- Ubuntu 14.04 x64
- Two ssh keys on my `~/.ssh` folder
- Two bitbucket accounts (one for personal projects and one for enterprise)
- A git repository only accessible with my primary key (~/.ssh/id_rsa)
- A git repository only accessible with my secondary key (~/.ssh/other)

I created a `~/.ssh/config` file with the contents:

```
Host bitbucket bitbucket.org
    Hostname bitbucket.org
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/other
    User git
```

And for the sake of sanity I added the second key using `ssh-add` as well. Running `ssh-add -l` lists both keys.

When using the command line, all git commands work like a charm, with both repositories. But when using Eclipse, I always get the `Invalid remote: origin` error when trying to clone or pull from the repository with the secondary key:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.NoRemoteRepositoryException: git@bitbucket.org:myuser/myrepository.git: conq: repository access denied.
```

I added the secondary key at `Window > Preferences > Network Connections > SSH2 > Private keys`, and set the `GIT_SSH` environment variable to point to my `ssh` executable:

```
$echo $GIT_SSH
/usr/bin/ssh
```

I've restarted Eclipse and even the OS several times, with no luck.

Since I can use git from the command line without problems, I tend to believe there's something wrong with Eclipse.

How to use multiple Git SSH keys on Eclipse? Or how to force Eclipse to use my secondary key on a single project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Host bitbucket bitbucket.org`? You don't declare multiple entry names on one `Host` section.

I would expect to see in a ssh config file declaring multiple keys:

```
Host bitbucketuserA
    Hostname bitbucket.org
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    User git

Host bitbucketuserB
    Hostname bitbucket.org
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/other
    User git
```

And you would use ssh url like

```
bitbucketuserA:userA/myrepo1
bitbucketuserB:userB/myrepo2
```

(this is similar to what I suggested for "[How to work on personal GitHub repo from office computer whose SSH key is already added to a work related GitHub account?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12066973/6309)")

Comment: That file was based on the accepted answer from [this question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419566/best-way-to-use-multiple-ssh-private-keys-on-one-client). Changing the ssh url for each project worked - thanks!