# Access different Gitlab servers from one machine

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

- Accessing company's gitlab from home -> no problem.
- Now try to access 2nd gitlab server at home (on a Raspberry Pi) -> being ask for password and access denied.
- Server seems to run just fine, can access web interface, configured it, added users, groups and a project.

I made a new SSH key (additional to the one I use to access the company gitlab server), added it to the ssh config file and put it in my profile on the gitlab server. (I do want to use another one for this server!)

I also changed the git global config user and email, but that did not help either.

This is what I did and got:

- I Tried to clone my test project in a bash:

  `git clone git@RPGL:testgroup/TestProject.git`

What I got is this:

```
Cloning into 'TestProject'...
Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address 'bladibla IP6 address here' to the list of known hosts.
git@rpgl's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
git@rpgl's password:
```

(If you need more info, please say so.)

Comment: Verify with `ssh -vvv git@rpgl` that ssh is using the right key. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1595848/7976758 for a lot of details about ssh configuration and debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you `~/.ssh/config` references the right ssh private key, as I mention in "[What steps must I take to consistently push to two Github accounts using SSH?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45228981/6309)"

Your remote Git URL should then be

```
anHostEntry:auser/arepo.git
```

Comment: Okay, it took me a while but after following your explanations and also deleting my ssh keys and creating new ones, I finally got it to work. Thanks a lot!