# Jenkins Git connection

Tags: git, authentication, jenkins

Getting this error while setting the git config in the Source Code Management section, the repository url is private like this `exampleip:/home/project/git-repo/single_login.git` not from github

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h exampleip:/home/project/git-repo/single_login.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

i tried setting up username and password in the jenkins credential provider and still doesnt work.

the clone that i do for the project in terminal was like this `git clone username@exampleip:/home/project/git-repo/single_login.git` this ask for password that once supplied it works

i think that somehow he is inputing the user/pass in a wrong way, anybody have an idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An scp-like ssh URL `exampleip:/home/project/git-repo/single_login.git` means the account running Jenkins will look for [an `~/.ssh/config` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45228981/6309), with an `Host exampleip` entry.

```
Host exampleip
  HostName exampleip.ip
  User username
  IdentityFile /path/to/id_rsa_username
```

Make sure `id_rsa_username.pub` is registered to your remote example server, at `~username/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Then it will work.

But you need to make sure of who is running Jenkins, in order to set the `~/.ssh/config` file at the right place.

Comment: thanks with this config in the ~/.ssh/config file with the user jenkins i was able to connect to the server