# How to change the Git credentials in PhpStorm?

Tags: git, phpstorm

I have used another username and password to work on a project and now I need to log in with different username for same project. I tried to pull codes for the worked projects but it is not working, since my older username has been removed. I try to change credentials but I don't see any option in PhpStorm.

I tried following command but not working:

```
git credential-osxkeychain erase host=github.com protocol=https
```

Any help? (I'm working on MAC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried following command but not working:

```
git credential-osxkeychain erase host=github.com protocol=https
```

That should actually be:

```
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https" | git credential-osxkeychain erase
```

Since [IntelliJ product are using Git from command-line](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000325944-How-to-change-remote-git-repositories-credentials-), check first if your credential helper is osxkeychain:

```
git config credential.helper
```

And try to follow the steps I mention in "[Why is Git using a wrong account (with osxkeychain)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53220427/6309)"

[Ratha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/946137/ratha) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55584962/how-to-change-the-git-credentials-in-phpstorm/55585232?noredirect=1#comment97868004_55585232):

> I went through the keychain app and deleted.. now it is working.

Comment: Yes, my credential helper is osxkeychain. That is why, I tried above command.When I run that command it didn't print anything and didn't end up with new line(it is running so long) ANy it didnt workout. Thanks for that post, I went through the keychain app and deleted.. now it is working

Comment: @Ratha Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 3):

I can't really answer for a MAC, but on Windows later version of Jetbrains' products store its credentials in a password vault.

In the case of PhpStorm 2019, it uses the KeePass database and the location of the DB can be found in Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Passwords.

It's also possible that Git is configured differently can look at `git config credential.helper` to determine what your configuration currently is, being on a Mac it's probably configured with osxkeychain.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to
Control Panel->"Credentials"->Windows Credentials->github/gitlab credentials
then update your password.