# How to add SSH Private Key to Intellij for Git

Tags: git, intellij-idea

When I use Git, I usually use the command line. so to push changes to the server. I add the public key to the SSH session using:

```
$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add "D:/Dev/Books Spaces/Version Control with Git and GitHub/SSH/key"
Enter passphrase for D:/Dev/Books Spaces/Version Control with Git and GitHub/SSH/key:
Identity added: D:/Dev/Books Spaces/Version Control with Git and GitHub/SSH/key (me*****d@outlook.com)
```

Now I would like to use intellij using SSH. How Can I add the private key to intellij? Right now it prints the message: 
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you ssh key is not a standard one (in `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\id_rsa`), you would need to make a `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\config` file in order to reference said key

```
Host github
  Hostname github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile "D:/Dev/Books Spaces/Version Control with Git and GitHub/SSH/key"
```

Then try the origin remote URL `github:xxxx/tacos01.git`

Comment: Thanks that worked. do you have a link to article on this I would like to read more on this.

Comment: @usertest Great! I remember using that back in 2012 (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12066973/6309). All the parameters of an SSH config file are described in https://www.ssh.com/ssh/config. Examples: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-ssh-config-file-on-linux-unix/